# VBA hide unhide rows based on user number entry

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to write a macro that unhides and hides columns based on user entry. 
It should unhide e.g. 3 columns if user enters "3" in a defined field and so on...

Here is the code that works fine if I do it for Rows. However for columns it does not work.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Target.Address = "$C$2" Then
            Range("G:L").EntireColumns.Hidden = True
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim imax As Integer
            Dim str1 As String
            Dim str2 As String
            imax = 5

            If Range("C2").Value > 0 And Range("C2") <= imax Then
                i = Range("C2").Value
                str1 = "7:" & 7 + i
                str2 = 7 + i & ":12"
                Range(str1).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                Range(str2).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you SJR, Thank you Dorian, both codes work really good! However because columns to hide/unhide are years (2018, 2019, 2020 and so on) I want to unhide starting from the first year. So I had to modify the code a little. Here is the result:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)                                 

    Dim MyRng As Range
    Dim Hide1 As Integer
    Dim Hide2 As Integer

If Target.Address = "$C$2" Then 

    Hide1 = 7                                                                     
    Hide2 = 14                                                                   
    Set MyRng = Range(Columns(Hide1), Columns(Hide2))   

    MyRng.Hidden = True                                                    

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim imax As Integer

    Dim str1 As Integer
    Dim str11 As Integer

    Dim str2 As Integer
    Dim str22 As Integer

    imax = 9


    If Range("C2").Value > 0 And Range("C2") <= imax Then         

         i = Range("C2").Value                                                      
         str1 = 7
         str11 = 7 + i                                                                    

         str2 = 7 + i
         str22 = 15

         Range(Columns(str1), Columns(str11)).Hidden = False       
         Range(Columns(str2), Columns(str22)).Hidden = True         

End If
End If



End Sub
```

Comment: May I ask you to accept my answer :  [look here to see how to accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Kindest regards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try by doing like that (**The last Code should be yours try it**) :

```
Sub tryme()

Dim MyRng As Range

Set MyRng = Columns("C:D")

MyRng.Hidden = True


End Sub
```

In your case if you want to Hide column with the number of the column and not the letter you should do stuff like this :

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange()

Dim MyRng As Range
Dim ColumnsToHide1 As Integer
Dim ColumnsToHide2 As Integer

ColumnsToHide1 = 1
ColumnsToHide2 = 5

Set MyRng = Range(Columns(ColumnsToHide1), Columns(ColumnsToHide2))

MyRng.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

So maybe your code would be like this : **give this a try** :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Target.Address = "$C$2" Then
            Range("G:L").EntireColumns.Hidden = True
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim imax As Integer
            Dim str1 As Integer
            Dim str11 As Integer

            Dim str2 As Integer
            Dim str22 As Integer

            Dim MyRng1 As Range
            Dim MyRng2 As Range

            imax = 5

            If Range("C2").Value > 0 And Range("C2") <= imax Then
                i = Range("C2").Value
                str1 = 7
                str11 = 7 + i
                str2 = 7 + i
                str22 = 12

                Range(Columns(str1), Columns(str11)).Hidden = True
                Range(Columns(str2), Columns(str22)).Hidden = True

            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This would hide A:C if you entered 3.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$C$2" Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
            Range("A1").Resize(, Target.Value).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```